# How to limit freebase results by release date?

Tags: freebase, mql

How can I limit the retrieved results by release date, when I am trying to get a list of books in a time interval?
I have tried with the following query, but it doesn't seem to work (still retrieves books from after 1900:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=   [{"type":"/book/book","id":null,"name":null,"/book/written_work/author":   [],"/book/written_work/date_of_first_publication>":"1900","/book/book/genre":   [],"/book/written_work/subjects":[],"limit":10,"key":   {"namespace":"/wikipedia/en_id","value":null}}]&indent=1

Also how do you select that you want the release date returned, when you use the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user007 mentioned, you've got the sign of your comparison wrong.  To get the actual date returned, just ask for it the same way you would normally, by including the property name with no value:

```
[{"type":"/book/book",
"id":null,
"name":null,
"/book/written_work/author": [],
"/book/written_work/date_of_first_publication<":"1900",
"/book/written_work/date_of_first_publication": null,
"/book/book/genre": [],
"/book/written_work/subjects":[],
"limit":10,
"key": {"namespace":"/wikipedia/en_id","value":null}}]
```

Note that the date_of_first_publication field is likely to be substantially less well populated than the date of the editions, so you may want to consider changing your query to book who have at least one edition published before 1900.

I've done a substantial amount of work with the Freebase book data, so feel free to message me if you need more help.

Comment: How would you construct such a query? (getting books with at least one edition before eg. 1900)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you can't work it out on your own, start a new question with the details of what you tried and how far you've gotten and I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

date_of_first_publication>":"1900" change to date_of_first_publication<":"1900" so it won't "retrieves books from after 1900"